# Finitely generated G-representation has "enough" simple quotients?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a finitely generated representation of a group $G$. The case of interest is where $G$ is infinite and $V$ is infinite dimensional.

Then a standard Zorn's Lemma argument can be used to show that $V$ has irreducible quotients. Does it have "enough"? One way to make this precise: does $V$ inject into the product of its irreducible quotients?

Comment: Unless you make further assumptions about characteristic of structure, no. You are basically claiming that the module V is semi simple.

Comment: Can you explain why the conclusion is "basically claiming" semisimplicity?

Comment: The point is that, without assuming that the characteristic of the field is $0$ or relatively prime to the group order, the answer to your question is no even for finite dimensional representations of finite groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G=\langle a\rangle$ the infinite cyclic group, and $V=\mathbb{Q}^2$, with $a$ acting (on the right) through the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&1\end{array}\right)$. Your claim then is equivalent to the matrix being diagonalizable, which it is not.
One can extend this example to infinite dimension by taking a direct sum with the regular module, which produces a counterexample to the claim for infinite-dimensional $V$.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps it's a misunderstanding of wording, but I am not "claiming" anything in the original post, just asking a question...

Comment: Sorry -- Claim was shorter than hypothesize